# Optimal way to pass parameters into Supplier e.g. for CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, completable-future, supplier

Sorry, I am pretty sure something like this must have been asked already, but I just can't find the answer.

Say, there's a service class `ChessEngineService` which has an instance method:
`String getBestMove(Query query);` 
There's also a client of the service which currently making synchronous calls to the service as follows:
`String move = chessEngineService.getBestMove(query);`

Because this call is blocking and can potentially take a long time execute, there's a need to make the invocation asynchronous e.g. using `CompletableFuture`:
`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(chessEngineService::getBestMove).thenAccept(...)`

The problem though, `Supplier` for `supplyAsync()` doesn't take any parameters since it's just a parameterless `get()`.

I tried to introduce an instance variable for `Query`, a setter for it in `ChessEngineService`, and an overloaded version of `getBestMove()` with no parameters to use the aforementioned `Query` variable internally, but I don't like such a solution mainly because `chessEngineService` should remain stateless.

Would be grateful for better ideas.

Comment: `supplyAsync(() -> chessEngineService.getBestMove(query))` (where both `chessEngineService` and `query` are fields/variables within scope)

Comment: Using a method reference is a nice way to improve clarity when you can, but sometimes you can't.

Comment: You can use `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(query) .applyAsync(chessEngineService::getBestMove)` but there is no advantage in doing it this way, compared to the alternative using a lambda expression shown above.

Answer (score 1):

People enjoy method references (`typeOrInstance::method`) because they do almost everything a normal lambda can do, all while being (subjectively) cleaner, clearer, and easier to read/understand.

You have run headfirst into one of the few things they ***cannot*** do, but a normal lambda ***can*** do -- Method references cannot take in state from their local scope (unless you use the instance method reference form, more on that later).

So, understanding that, let's go back to your example.

You have a method `getBestMove`, and you want to call it on your instance `chessEngineService` (whose type is the same name). Specifically, you want to pass in your variable `query`.

Well, the easiest way to do it would be to use a normal lambda expression. Here is a reworking of your example.

```java
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> chessEngineService.getBestMove(query)).thenAccept(...)
```

Now, because you are doing the normal lambda form (specifically, the lambda expression form), you ***CAN*** grab state from the local scope, and insert into your `Supplier` -- even though the `Supplier` takes no parameters.

This is one of the abilities of lambdas, and why there are multiple forms of them. The method reference form isn't just more concise, it communicates information -- a method reference form is not able to include any local state, other than listing the instance as the method provider. To clarify, if you have a method reference `String::length`, you are using the class name, and therefore, this is a pure, stateless lambda. Whereas, if you did it like this `someString::length`, the only state passed in is the instance `someString`.

Method references allow you to quickly realize that the lambda has exactly 0 or 1 piece of local state included in it, whereas a normal lambda can have as many as you choose to include (`() -> Arrays.asList(local1, local2, local3, local4, etc)`).